# Style not compatible with Jupyter-Book when using python-sphinx autodoc to generate API documentation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, jupyterbook

I'd love to use the so elegant Jupyter-Book to construct documentation for my packages. I've tried quite a lot, and here is an example I'm finalizing those days :

- the package is available on a gitlab repository https://framagit.org/nlp/iamtokenizing
- the associated documentation is constructed (almost) automatically by calling `jupyter-book build documentation/` on CI/CL-deployment of the master branch of the repository, and visible there : https://nlp.frama.io/iamtokenizing

One can see I use

- jupyter-notebook to generate user guides or tutorials,
- markdown to generate simple static pages without codes, and
- [sphinx autodoc](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/advanced/developers.html) to generate api documentation. Note I'm fairly newbie using sphinx and autodoc.

I'd like to enhance the publication style of the auto-generated api documentation. As one can see, e.g. on [this page](https://nlp.frama.io/iamtokenizing/api/chargrams.html), there is no right sidebar in the API documentation, whereas one may want to write the names of the class methods, or module functions there.

Also, the parameters list might be better presented in indented lists instead of being queued in parenthesis, and the name of the class might be shorter, for instance only the name of the class, not the path to it might appear. In short, I'd prefer having

```py
class BaseTokenizer(string: str = '', 
                    subtoksep: chr = ' ', 
                    intervals: Union[None, EvenSizedSortedSet] = None, 
                    tokens: list = [])
```

instead of the monolithic presentation

```py
class iamtokenizing.base_tokenizer.BaseTokenizer(string: str = '', subtoksep: 
chr = ' ', intervals: Union[None, 
extractionstring.even_sized_sorted_set.EvenSizedSortedSet] = None, tokens: list = [])
```

Is there a way to do all of that, or should I consider raising an issue instead ?

Comment: The HTML is a bunch of inline `span`s, so you could apply custom CSS to get the appearance you want in a `custom.css`, then include that in your `conf.py`. https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files

Comment: @StevePiercy That you for your comment. The point is: since I'm new to sphinx and jupyter-book, I do not know how this conf.py is read while using sphinx through jpuyter-book ... any idea where to get some infos ?

Comment: Start with the Sphinx docs? There's a nice tutorial.

Comment: @StevePiercy: As far as I can tell, Jupyterbook does not use conf.py; instead there is a _config.yml file: https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/customize/config.html

Comment: @FraSchelle: "there is no right sidebar" - That's one problem. "the parameters list might be better presented" - That's a different problem. Please ask about one problem at a time.

Comment: @mzjn Thank you ! Do you have any idea on the resolution?

Comment: Regarding the display of parameters, there is a similar old issue (not about jupyter-book specifically) https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1514.